# Ideal way to close connections in RestAssured?

Tags: rest, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am using RestAssured for API automation. We have a huge application with so many api calls. So, what could be better way to close the connection after response has been received properly. In that way, I will not be worried about connection leakage.

Below is my code:

```
RestAssuredConfig restAssuredConfig = RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(EncoderConfig.encoderConfig().appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false)).httpClient(HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig().setParam("http.connection.timeout", 60000).setParam("http.socket.timeout", 300000).setParam("http.conn-manager.timeout", 300000));

RequestSpecification requestSpecification = RestAssured.given().config(restAssuredConfig).relaxedHTTPSValidation();
```

Should I specify ConnectionConfig like below ?

```
RestAssured.config().connectionConfig(ConnectionConfig.connectionConfig().closeIdleConnectionsAfterEachResponse());
```

Should I use closeIdleConnectionsAfterEachResponse() method ? or closeIdleConnectionsAfterEachResponseAfter(long idleTime, TimeUnit timeUnit) method ?

Please help. Thanks in advance.